# I can't start mongodb serve after I try to restart it on centos

Tags: mongodb, ssh, centos

Everytime after I restart mongodb, it failed, need help.

After inputting:

```
sudo systemctl start mongod
```

It shows:

```
Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Then I input

```
systemctl status mongod.service
```

It tells me

```
 ● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since 六 2020-06-20 07:57:51 CST; 6min ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 31367 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 31365 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 31363 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 31362 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

6月 20 07:57:51 VM_0_10_centos systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
6月 20 07:57:51 VM_0_10_centos systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process ...2
6月 20 07:57:51 VM_0_10_centos systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database....
6月 20 07:57:51 VM_0_10_centos systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered fail....
6月 20 07:57:51 VM_0_10_centos systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Which I don't know how to solve, need help.

The mongod.log goes as follows:

```
    2020-06-20T00:19:20.338+0800 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2020-06-20T00:19:20.338+0800 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down session sweeper thread
2020-06-20T00:19:20.338+0800 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] Finished shutting down session sweeper thread
2020-06-20T00:19:20.338+0800 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down journal flusher thread
2020-06-20T00:19:20.427+0800 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] Finished shutting down journal flusher thread
2020-06-20T00:19:20.427+0800 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] Shutting down checkpoint thread
2020-06-20T00:19:20.427+0800 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] Finished shutting down checkpoint thread
2020-06-20T00:19:20.460+0800 I  STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2020-06-20T00:19:20.460+0800 I  CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2020-06-20T00:19:20.460+0800 I  CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] shutting down
```

Comment: try checking the log file `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log` for potential reason

Comment: Thanks, and I have added the log content to my question, still dont know what to do.